# Alternatives for flush_handlers in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have handlers in my Ansible playbook and I want to trigger these notifies immediately. How can this be achieved without calling the `meta_handler = flush_handler`?
This works fine in Ansible 2.5.6 but after this version there is a warning displayed saying:

> [WARNING]: flush_handlers task does not support when conditional

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have a `when` condition on the `flush_handler` when you want to fire it immediately?

Comment: without adding this meta tag notify handlers does not get called. The when condition is for the whole block which includes flush_handler

Comment: is there anyway i can trigger the handlers immediately?

Comment: Still the question remains. "Why do you have a when condition ..." Put the flush_handlers after the block. Either the handler is notified within the block, or not.

Comment: @VladimirBotka - I came here because (in my case) I have an entire role that is conditionally included. And inside that role, I need to flush handlers because certain tasks rely on the handler from the previous tasks being run. Putting the handler after the block (or, in my case, after the role) wouldn't really help...

Comment: @VladimirBotka this. did you find a workaround?

Comment: The workaround would depend on your use case. Generally, a condition has no effect on meta. The [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41313) is still open. AFAIK it's not possible to suppress this warning.

Answer (score 3):

It's an open issue [meta: flush_handlers doesn't honor when clause #41313](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41313).

<sup>(2021-04-20 the issue is still open. Please comment here if status changes)</sup>

Quoting my [comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/41313#issuecomment-440647271):

> Let me describe a valid scenario (below). "flush_hadlers" is needed after tasks abc.yml complete and before tasks def.yml start. But the file with the tasks xyz.yml is imported when OS is RH only. Here Ansible complains:

```
[WARNING]: flush_handlers task does not support when conditional
```

**It would be nice to be able to suppress the warning.**

```
# cat xyz.yml
- include_tasks: abc.yml
- meta: flush_handlers
- include_tasks: def.yml
```

```
# cat playbook.yml
  ...
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: xyz.yml
      when: (ansible_os_family == "RedHat" )
```